# How to output to the original directory when renaming recursively?

Tags: linux, bash, devops

#### dirs example:

```
./lv1/lvN/*.json

./lv1/*.json

demo.sh
```

---

#### Here's my script:

```bash
# ...

# Get all paths recursively

# exclude dir

find . -name *.json > json_list

# Read line by line, rename and output to the original directory

while read -r line_content; do

    mv "${line_content}" ${RANDOM}.json # How do I export to the original directory?

done < json_list

# ...
```

---

#### How do I export to the original directory?

Tried IFS or AWK to split the path into two fields, but is there a better way?

Comment: Your `find` statement reports all files which are below your working directory. Technically speaking, it reports all files which are either below `.` (the working directory) or below a directory where the name ends in `.json`, but since the latter is searched for in your working directory as well,  this does not add anything to the outcome. You have written equally well `find . >json.list`

Comment: `RANDOM` is a predefined variable. `$RANDOM` outputs a random number. Is that actually what you want, or do you want to retain the original filename?

Comment: is "original directory" the place where the file was found, or the top level of the find? ie. for file `./a/b/c.json` are you wanting to do `mv ./a/b/c.json ./a/b/d.json` or `mv ./a/b/c.json ./` ?

Comment: in your find commmandline, `*.json` should probably be `-name '*.json'`

Comment: "rename and output to the original directory" doesn't make sense. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for

```
mv "${line_content}" "${line_content%/*}/${RANDOM}.json"
```

See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${line_content%/*}`.

Comment: Great, it works fine. I haven't found this usage in years of writing shells. `str="/opt/dev/demo.json" && echo "${str%/*}"`